# Windows 10 Insider Preview causes blank screen

Tags: graphics-card, windows-10-preview

I decided to install the Windows 10 Insider Preview on a laptop and I am having a strange issue.  The Dell Latitude 6410 with an Intel graphics chip runs Win 7 perfectly fine.  I did a fresh installation of Win 10 IP and it works fine for about a minute the screen goes blank even the backlight turns off.  If I hit a key, the backlight turns on, but no graphics.  It looks like the graphics goes into a suspended state and cant come out of it.  After I reboot, after the Windows logo, the screen goes blank.  I reinstalled Win 7 and did an upgrade thinking maybe having the proper video driver already installed will help, but the same thing happens.

Any thoughts?

Comment: WDDM was updated 3 times since Windows 7 was released. It is now WDDM 2.0 and is vastly different then the WDDM that Windows 7 had. Intel currently only has beta display drivers for Windows 10.  If the same thing is happening now with Windows 7 then its unlikely a software problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally got around to playing with it.  The display works on an external monitor, which is good.  Once I was able to see the screen I saw the display driver was failing.  I uninstalled the video driver and the graphics worked on the laptop again.  However, once it auto-detected the driver and installed it, it stopped working again.  Unfortunately the Intel display drivers for Win 10 are still in beta.  I guess I will just have to wait for the driver to be updated.